# How to throw AssertionError for duplicate values in list of OrderedDict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a list of OrderedDict. The OrderedDict is a tuple of key/value pair:

```
dict_lists = [[OrderedDict([('name', 'Good check'), ('url',
              'https://www.facebook.com/'), ('lag', 10), ('tags',
              ['team:team 4', 'section 1', 'section 2']), ('headers',
              OrderedDict([('Location', 'http://facebook.com/')]))]),
              OrderedDict([('name', 'Bad check'), ('url',
              'https://www.google.com/'), ('lag', 5), ('tags',
              ['team:team 1'])]), OrderedDict([('name', 'Bad check'),
              ('url', 'https://www.microsoft.com/'), ('lag', 5), ('tags'
              , ['team:team 5'])])]]
```

I'm trying to throw an AssertionError when there are duplicate values for the `"name"` key.

Currently, it works for keys because I believe it throws an AssertionError for duplicate keys:

> AssertionError: 'name' unexpectedly found in ['name', 'url', 'lag',
>   'tags', 'headers']

Code for duplicate keys:

```
import unittest
from collections import OrderedDict
    keys = []
            for dict_list in dict_lists:
                for dictionary in dict_list:
                    dict_keys = dictionary.keys()
                    for key in dict_keys:
                        self.assertNotIn(key, keys)
                        keys.append(key)
```

How do I get it work for duplicate values ( just for the `"name"` key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your values for that key in a set, then test against that set:

```
name_values = {}
for dict_list in dict_lists:
    for dictionary in dict_list:
        if 'name' in dictionary:
            value = dictionary['name']
            self.assertNotIn(value, name_values)
            name_values.add(value)
```

You should really also use a set for your keys. There is also no need to call the `keys()` method, looping over the dictionary directly gives you the keys too.

If you want to combine the loops together, you could just test if the current key is equal to `'name'`:

```
keys = {}
name_values = {}

for dict_list in dict_lists:
    for dictionary in dict_list:
        for key in dictionary:
            self.assertNotIn(key, keys)
            keys.add(key)
            if key == 'name':
                value = dictionary[key]
                self.assertNotIn(value, name_values)
                name_values.add(value)
```

Note that the fact that your dictionaries are ordered makes no difference to the solution here.

Comment: is there a cleaner way to write this without the 3 for loops?

Comment: @nara_l: you could create a generator expression that yields the dictionaries: `dictionaries = (d for n in dict_list for d in n)`, then on the next line: `for dictionary in dictionaries:`. Or rethink your data structures to not use such a nested structure.

Comment: re-thinking the nested structure seems to be the better option then, thanks!